# C# - Oracle Stored Procedure return RefCursor without rows

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, oracle-manageddataaccess, ref-cursor, odp.net-managed

My Stored Procedure call does return 7 rows, but not when I call it through Oracle Managed data access.

**Code :**

```
    string _connectionString = 
        String.Format("Data Source={0};User Id={1};Password={2};",
            tbDataSource.Text, tbUser.Text, tbPassword.Text);


    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(_connectionString)){
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand()){
            cmd.CommandText = "XXCOOT_QUERIES.getWarehouses";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // Parameters
            OracleParameter p1 = new OracleParameter();
            p1.ParameterName = "inumActivityId";
            p1.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
            p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            p1.Size = 10;
            p1.Value = 108;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);

            OracleParameter cursor = new OracleParameter();
            cursor.ParameterName = "ocursWarehouses";
            cursor.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
            cursor.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(cursor);

            OracleParameter p2 = new OracleParameter();
            p2.ParameterName = "ostrErrCode";
            p2.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
            p2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            p2.Size = 2000;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            OracleDataReader reader = null;

            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            using (reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
                dt.Load(reader);
                this.tbResult.Text = "Rows Count : " +
                    dt.Rows.Count.ToString(); // Returns: "Rows Count : 0"

                this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
                // Returns : " | Column1 | Column2 | "
                //             |-------- | --------|
            }
        }
    }
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
PROCEDURE getWarehouses
     ( inumActivityId   in   varchar2
     , ocursWarehouses  out  grefCursorType
     , ostrErrCode      out  varchar2
 )
IS
    lextorg varchar2(150);
BEGIN
    FND_CLIENT_INFO.Set_Org_Context(inumActivityId);
   lextorg := null;

   SELECT b.GENERIC_EXTERNAL_ORGANIZATION
   INTO   lextorg
   FROM   HR_ORGANIZATION_INFORMATION a
   ,      HR_ORGANIZATION_INFORMATIO_DFV b
   WHERE  a.organization_id = to_number(inumActivityId)
   AND    a.ORG_INFORMATION_CONTEXT = 'Operating Unit Information'
   AND    a.rowid = b.rowid;

IF lextorg is null THEN

    OPEN ocursWarehouses FOR
        SELECT ood.organization_code  organization_code
         ,      ood.organization_name  name
         FROM   org_organization_definitions  ood
         ,      mtl_parameters                mp
         ,      mtl_parameters_dfv            mp_dfv
         WHERE ood.operating_unit = to_number(inumActivityId)
         AND   sysdate <= nvl(disable_date,sysdate)
         AND   ood.organization_id = mp.organization_id
         AND   mp.rowid = mp_dfv.row_id
         AND   upper(mp_dfv.warehouse_type) in ('INTERNAL','EXTERNAL')
         ORDER by organization_name;

ELSE

    OPEN ocursWarehouses FOR
        SELECT ood.organization_code  organization_code
        ,      ood.organization_name  name
        FROM   org_organization_definitions  ood
        ,      mtl_parameters                mp
        ,      mtl_parameters_dfv            mp_dfv
        WHERE -ood.operating_unit = to_number(inumActivityId)
        AND sysdate <= nvl(disable_date,sysdate)
        AND   ood.organization_id = mp.organization_id
        AND   mp.rowid = mp_dfv.row_id
        AND   upper(mp_dfv.warehouse_type) in ('INTERNAL','EXTERNAL')
        ORDER by organization_name;
END/
```

**At execution :**
  No warnings, no errors (all parameters are valids)

**My problem :**
  Any rows are returned (instead of the 7 expected rows) but I retrieve the schema (column names are corrects).

---

**Environment :**

- Windows x64
- .NET Framework : 4.0
- Oracle Client installed (v11.2) but not necessary
- Oracle Data Provider .NET : Oracle.ManagedDataAccess (v121.1.2)

Comment: Can you post the signature of the ORACLE PROC please? Given that your reader is returning the columns (and assuming they are the correct names), it seems the refcursor isfine. It may be more likely that the input parameters are causing data to be filtered incorrectly. Also, try checking the `ostrErrCode` parameter - perhaps it has info.

Comment: ostrErrCode is always NULL and I cannot access to the signature of the ORACLE PROC but I am sure that the number and format of the parameter are corrects ...

Comment: `DESC XCOOT_QUERIES.getWarehouses`? Also just to be sure try setting `cmd.BindByName = true` - by default Oracle binds by position which can cause issues.

Comment: `cmd.BindByName = true` does not work : always the same results (only the schema).

Comment: Its PL/SQL - execute in SqlPlus or Oracle Sql Dev etc.

Comment: I updated the initial post

Comment: Should have seen this earlier ... p1 is `OracleDbType.Varchar2` but you are passing in integer literal 108. Change to string literal `"108"` Also, drop the size on p1, you don't need it on input params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after months and months, I've found the cause of my problem :

My Stored Procedure use **view(s) in its FROM clause**. This (these) view(s) use the *LOB datatype* (I found this problem thanks to a Oracle returned error).

Comment: And...you did what to resolve? Wait for the next version, remove the views? What?

Answer (score 0):

The same was happening to me and my problem was my connection string and that I wasn't opening the connection ...